# Change object's global variable value using variable to access object's global variable

Tags: python

**experiment.py**

```
global x
x = False

class func1:        

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def hello(self):
        # global x
        print x
```

**new.py**

```
import experiment

object = experiment.func1()
z = "x"
experiment.z = True        # Expection is experiment.z should work as experiment.x 
experiment.hello()
```

**Output:** # o/p should be true as I am trying to acheve `t.x = True`

```
>>> 
False
>>>
```

**Question is:** Is there a way to do it or this concept is wrong?

Comment: In new.py `t` (in `t.z`) doesn't seem to be defined before, do you mean `experiment.x = True` instead?

Comment: yes I meant experiment.x...i have updated the same...thanks...i want to write it in different way experiment.z = True where z=x

Comment: Why do you want to change the name? Can you give an example where this gives you an advantage instead of using `experiment.x`?

Comment: suppose i have multiple global variable & I want to update only one of them

Comment: Then you still can call them by their name: `experiment.x`, `experiment.y`, etc.. Another thing is the doubt if it really is a good idea to use global variables, why not just define the variables in your class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are a lot of errors in your code and some inconsistencies.

You've just added the new attribute to your instance of `func1`.

```
z = "x"
t.z = True
```

This is probably what are you looking for:

**exp.py**

```
x = False


class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def hello(self):
        print self.x

t = Test(x)
t.hello()
```

**newp.py**

```
from exp import Test, t

t.x = True
t.hello()

>>> False
>>> True
```

Comment: In your code...suppose i want to write t.x = True  but in a different way....like t.z = True where z=x

Answer (score 0):

using setattr(object, name, value)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr